# Unable to Drag & Drop in Selenium WebDriver 3.6

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to drag & drop but its not working.

Here is my code.

Please help, I have applied so much time on this, but it is still not working.

*Chrome Version: 62.0.3202.75

ChromeDriver :  2.33

Selenium : 3.6*

```
public class Drag_And_Drop {
static String baseURl="https://www.google.com";
static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeMethod
public void openBrowser() {     
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(baseURl);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void verifyCount() {

    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lst-ib']"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("jqwidget drag and drop");
    searchBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);     

    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("jQuery DragDrop, DragDrop plug-in, Drag and Drop ... - jQWidgets"));
    link.click();       

    driver.switchTo().frame(0);

    WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jqxWidgete3128591f541']"));
    source.click();

    WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cart']"));       

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();
}   

@AfterMethod
public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.quit();
}
}
```

Comment: Was the same test passing before (<3.6) and having problem with 3.6 version?

Comment: @Rao : No the code is not running on any other version also, after so much time I have deleted all previous versions of FF, Chrome, Selenium jars, and now trying to use latest ones.

Comment: @Rao: It will be a great help if you please connect team viewer .

Comment: Put the code in try catch and try to see the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is here:

```
WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jqxWidgete3128591f541']"));
```

You are trying to find the element with the id but, actually, this id is always different. If you open 2 different browser and try to inspect the same element, you will notice this.

You could try to locate all the elements with classname **"draggable-demo-product jqx-rc-all jqx-draggable"**, and after add the elements that you want.

In the following example, all the elements are added:

```
    //WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jqxWidgete3128591f541']"));
    WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='shop']"));
    List<WebElement> listDraggableElement=source.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='draggable-demo-product jqx-rc-all jqx-draggable']"));

    WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cart']"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    for(WebElement el: listDraggableElement)
    {
        System.out.println(el.getText());
        actions.dragAndDrop(el, target).build().perform();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, You have saved my many days, as I have tried it lot of times and lot of effort but did not done it. Thanks a lot once again.Its working fine now. Thanks...

Comment: @AnubhavJain Happy to help :)